# How to interpret data types obtained from <typeinfo> library?

Tags: c++, pointers

Q1 - Since both `begin(arr)` & `&arr` will return hexadecimal pointer location of starting of the `arr`, wondering what is the difference between the outputs of data types printed by the following script?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 77};

    cout << typeid(begin(arr)).name() << " , " << typeid(&arr).name() << endl;
    cout << begin(arr) << " , " << &arr << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Pi , PA7_i
0x7ffc79a99500 , 0x7ffc79a99500
```

Q2 - how can we get decimal representation of hex pointer location?

Comment: `&arr` has type `int (*)[7]`  (i.e.  pointer to array of 7 `int`).  `std::begin(arr)` has type `int *` (i.e.  pointer to `int`). Since the first is encoded as `Pi` and the second as `PA7_i`  it seems possible that, in the encoding used in `typeid().name()` (implementation-defined), the leading `P` indicates pointer, the last character `i` means `int`, and `A7_` means array with 7 elements.  To print a pointer as decimal, convert to an appropriate integral type and output that (e.g.  `cout << std::ptrdiff_t(begin(arr))` since integral types are, by default, output as decimal.

Comment: please one question per question. When you have two questions you should open two questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Q1:

Note that `begin(arr)` and `&arr` are different things (with different types). `begin(arr)` gives the pointer to the 1st element of `arr` with type `int*`, `&arr` gives the pointer to the array `arr` with type `int (*)[7]`.